# Showing business entities in grids with only using a few properties

Tags: dto, entities

I am trying to get my head around business entities that you want to list in a grid or list where a user will pick one to edit/view.

Lets say I have an Entity that have a lot of properties and collections, but my Grid will only display like 2 properties to the user. Besides using lazy loading on collections what would be the best / efficient way to load this data and display to the user?

I am thinking of creating a DTO object with the required properties and pass that to the UI. But I am worrying about over populating DTO's.

Answer (score 0):

To do maintenance on an object you could allways use a Property Grid control if your are in c#.

With this you can view/edit collection and everything else.

Comment: How would a property grid help me?

Comment: You can use this to edit anykind of business object.  So you want to do administrator thing to your object, then with a property grid you can have only 1 form to do edits on all your object that need admin.  It will save you time and efforts.